# Is Poison consumed by the first attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, poison

Is a vial of Poison consumed by the first attack of such a weapon or I get the +1d4 Poison damage for each attack I do in one minute?

> **Poison, Basic.** *You can use the poison in this vial to coat one slashing or piercing
> weapon or up to three pieces of Ammunition. Applying the poison takes
> an action. A creature hit by the Poisoned weapon or Ammunition must
> make a DC 10 Constitution saving throw or take 1d4 poison damage. Once
> applied, the poison retains potency for 1 minute before drying.* (PHB, p. 153)

Rule as written I would say it would last for the full minute, unless there is another part i missed where it states otherwise?

Similarly, for **Injury Poisons** (DMG, p. 257), how long does the effect on the weapon last? (For example for **Serpent Venom (Injury)**).

Comment: Perfect. This has, however, already been asked and answered here [Can a single dose of poison applied to an edged weapon be used multiple times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59863/14878) so this will be closed as a duplicate. Duplicates aren't a bad thing though so don't feel like you've done wrong and have to delete this question. Duplicates actually provide more search terms that can help people find the "main" question.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Feel free to let us know whether the linked question matches yours; if not, feel free to edit your question to clarify what part's not already addressed in the linked question.