# How does the poison from the Poisoner feat work?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, poison, duration

I've seen in [previous discussions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59863/can-a-single-dose-of-poison-applied-to-an-edged-weapon-be-used-multiple-times) that "basic poison" from the PHB can be interpreted RAW to last for the full minute regardless of if you hit a creature, as opposed to the injury poison mechanic from the DMG.

Adding on to this, the poison from the Poisoner feat found in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (p. 80) is another outlier.

As a DM with some experience, I would be willing to rule that it functions as an advanced basic poison, in that it lasts for the full minute regardless of hits. However, for AL play for example, it might be more RAI to have it function as an injury poison.
Is there any clarification on this, or is it DM fiat?

**How does the poison from the Poisoner feat work?**

- Does it work like basic poison, per the PHB?
- Or is it an injury poison, per the DMG?
- Or something else?

Comment: Relevant meta: [Please avoid using the RAI acronym, or use it carefully & be clear in context](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7528/33569). You should probably rephrase that sentence to clarify the intended meaning.

Comment: Looking at the (currently only) answer, it would have been nice to quote the relevant parts of Poisoner feat, because it looks like the feat text already answers your question... Or if there is something unclear about the feat text, you could say what is unclear. I mean, if the answer is direct quote from from the feature you ask... Maybe more research before asking would have been in order.

Answer (score 8):

#### The poison loses its potency after 1 minute *or* after you hit a creature with the poisoned weapon/ammunition

The third benefit of the [Poisoner](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/poisoner) feat states (TCoE, p. 80):

> [...] Once applied to a weapon or piece of ammunition, the poison retains its potency for 1 minute or until you hit with the weapon or ammunition.  [...]